# Ads user data to a session when a login is performed

Tags: php, session, post, isset

Just learning PHP and I have a question from an assignment that I don't really understand

I need to write a PHP code snippet that adds user data to a session when a login is performed. The data that should be stored is ‘user_name’, ‘user_first_name’, and ‘user_last_name’. Note: the names of the data stored in the session are same names of the parameters that you get from the POST. Also, don’t forget to check that the POST variables exist and that they aren’t empty.

This is what I have so far, but I am pretty sure it's completely off:

```
if (isset($user_name, $user_first_name, $user_last_name) && !empty($user_name, $user_first_name, $user_last_name)) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['user_name'] = $user_name;
    $_SESSION['user_first_name'] = $user_first_name;
    $_SESSION['user_last_name'] = $user_last_name;
}
```

If anyone could help that would be great!

Comment: Are you encountering any specific errors or unexpected behaviors when using the code you've written?

Answer (score 0):

`!empty($user_name, $user_first_name, $user_last_name)`

should be

`(!empty($user_name) && !empty($user_first_name) && !empty($user_last_name))`